# How do I save «the learned state» in accord.net?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I am a beginner at machine learning and Accord.net. I see how I can train it and then use it, but in an enterprise setting, running this on a server, how do I persist the learnings of Accord .net. Do I need to save all training data and retrain every time the application is restarted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ususally there are Load and Save methods for persistance and re-creation of state.
At which specific model are you looking at?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying different models; classification mainly (if that is what you are asking)

Answer (score 10):

Import the Accord.IO namespace in your code, by adding

```
using Accord.IO;
```

at the top of your source file. This way, you will be able to use the [Serializer](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_IO_Serializer.htm)'s Save methods in any framework object. To load an object back from its serialized form, you can use Serializer.Load(string path).

Comment: It's safe to say this should be the accepted answer.